# Is there a way to change the root path of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Is it possible to change the root path of an iframe to another path
maybe in this way so all the other paths will change not to localhost or something else?

```
<iframe root-path='THE_NEW_PATH'
>
```

Comment: The `base` tag is part of the document contents. Therefore, if you are populating your IFRAME through its SRC attribute - you should ensure the HTML document has a proper `base` tag. If you are populating the IFRAME through SRCDOC - you can simply include a `base` tag in the attribute value. You can read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base There is no other way to enforce this onto IFRAMEs.